# Why all my repositories hosted on BitBucket are multiplies in Atlassian SourceTree?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have several regular projects hosted on BitBucket.
When I try to add one of it I see three lines per each project.
I checked that selection any of the line, resulting connected the same repository.

[image: Adding repository]

Anyone can tell my why it happening? And how to remove duplication?

Comment: Perhaps you have registered the bitbucket-account 3 times in SourceTree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanx [@Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen)!
It is because BitBucket account added several times.

I can't imaging how it can be but it realy is:

[image]

I'm sure that it is not my mistake.
I was installing SourceTree anywhere: at home on PC, on notebook, at work etc.
And always got multiple lines for each project, and always three lines.

I think it is some bug in SourceTree.